# Dual boot installation on hybrid (ssd + hdd) storage

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I am planning to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop.
My laptop specifications are:

```
i7-8750H
16GB RAM
GTX 1050Ti 4 GB
256 GB SSD + 1 TB HDD
```

Well, I am considering two options->

1. Installing both OS on SSD (128GB + 128 GB).
   Installing windows 10 on half of the SSD and other half with Ubuntu. And further dividing HDD into 2 
   parts for secondary storage for both the OS separately. The problem is I don't know how to set up 
   half of HDD for Ubuntu's secondary storage?
2. Installing Windows on HDD and Ubuntu on SSD.
   I am not giving preference to this option. I want to enjoy the fast startup speed of SSD. But will 
   consider this option only if 128GB isn't enough for either OS.

Note-> I want Ubuntu for programming and development, mostly for Deep Learning. While Windows for Visual Studio, Windows development, Microsoft Office, Abode Photoshop, Adobe XD, Abode Lightroom, Camtasia Studio.
Suggest better options/alternatives for my above methods if possible.

Also,  I came to know that I don't have to create `/home` separately as it will be installed in `/` (root). I think this will be perfect to save SSD space, as I might allocate more for either of them which is not required.

Comment: Option 1 sounds best to me. Install Windows first. Then using Windows disk management shrink it’s C: drive to around 128 GB. Install Ubuntu using the something else option for partitioning and use the rest of the ssd for a combined / and /home. Then with Ubuntu partition the HDD. Mount the portion for Ubuntu where you like. Perhaps /home/user/data where user is your user name. I’d keep /home on the ssd for speed. It contains plenty of config files that could slow things down if on the hdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 seems to be the best.

Both Ubuntu and Windows should be fine with 128GB each.

For the shared HDD, if you are going to use the same partition for both OS, that is fine but you will have to make sure that partition is formatted as `NTFS`.

If you will be using 2 separate partitions for Windows and Ubuntu, you can partition the Windows partition as `NTFS` and Ubuntu partition as `EXT4`. However, this will mean that you can't access the Ubuntu partition form Windows. But with this, you can keep Windows `Fast Startup` on even though it won't have much effect if you are using an SSD.

Anyway whatever method you chose, make sure that the partition you will use for Ubuntu is automounted. This can be done by editing the `fstab` file.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, it was a really perfect answer I was looking for.         Can you explain the last paragraph in more detail? "Partition for UBUNTU is automounted. This can be done by editing the "fstab" file. I also would like to know the reason, why we are doing it. And thanks again, your answer was really good.

Comment: @SarthakPurohit If you want that partition to appear automatically every time you log into Ubuntu, you can set it to automount. If you don't do this, you will have to mount it manually every time to use it.

Comment: @SarthakPurohit You can easily achieve this through GUI tools. (see https://www.fosslinux.com/4216/how-to-automount-hard-disk-partitions-in-ubuntu.htm#:~:text=Automounting%20hard%20disks%20and%20partitions%20in%20Ubuntu&text=Step%202)%20Select%20the%20hard,represented%20by%20the%20gear%20icon.&text=Step%203)%20Select%20%E2%80%9CEdit%20Mount%20Options%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D.&text=Step%204)%20Toggle%20the%20%E2%80%9CUser,Session%20Defaults%E2%80%9D%20option%20to%20OFF.). This is how you do it by editing the `/etc/fstab` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions.

Comment: @SarthakPurohit When you are using a partition shared between both Ubuntu and Windows, DO NOT DELETE ANYTHING YOU DID NOT MAKE. In Ubuntu, you can see all windows hidden files and hidden system files. Deleting these will lead to a heap of trouble. Likewise, in Windows, you can see all hidden Ubuntu files. Don't delete these either.

Comment: However, files that you delete from this partition in Ubuntu will probably not go to trash. If you wan't to make it go to trash, you will have to edit the fstab. Tell me if you want to do so.